# Transfer function not working in basic deposit and withdraw contract

Tags: solidity, remix, address.transfer

I have this simple contract used with remix.

```
pragma solidity^0.4.24;
```

contract test{
    mapping (address => uint) balances;
    function Deposit() public payable{
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
    function Withdraw() public{
        msg.sender.transfer(balances[msg.sender]);
        balances[msg.sender] = 0;
    }
    function CheckBalance() view public returns(uint){
        return balances[msg.sender];
    }
}

I can send the payable amount through remix, and the balance shows accordingly. The transaction will also show the correct value in wei. But withdrawing will result in a transaction of 0 wei.

The balance is deducted in the contract, but no transfer has occured to the msg.sender.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I just ran this in remix and it works as intended. Btw you have a vulnerability to reentrancy attacks in your `Withdraw` function.

Comment: Perhaps i don't know how to use remix properly? You had the proper value in the withdraw function? I am using ganache-cli now. I'll try the code out again with the test nets

Comment: I sent one ether and I withdraw one ether. Just be sure that you are withdrawing with the same address that you deposited. Do you have this in a testnet (ropsten maybe?) If so, please post here the address of your deployed contract

Comment: Oh. it works on Ropsten. Guess it's a ganache problem? Thanks for the headsup about the reentrancy attacks. I will mark answered when I figure out why ganache is having problems with this. Thanks Jaime!

Answer (score 1):

Ahh. I had my payable wei value wrong in Remix. There wasn't enough 0s. Check your 0s and units guys!

Thanks!